# Why to use Foolproof validation in ASP.NET MVC 2 and DataAnnotations 4?

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

I understand that Foolproof validation extends DA and adds support for validation attributes as listed [here](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/)

However, most of the validations that are listed can be in theory be accomplished by writing custom validators. Why would I need to use this library? Thanks

Comment: Why would you need to use MVC when you could write your own framework?

Comment: Good point. But I feel that writing new custom validators have been made very easy in MVC 2. Also, client side validation support can be added to custom validator as well removing the need for MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation.js

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box way of writing custom validators to validate against other runtime property values.